# Typescript intersection types with array of objects and an interface

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the intersection types. Here it is what I'm referring to:

```
type FooList = Foo[] & {
    bar: string
};

interface Foo {
    baz: string;
}
```

After a lot of fiddling I'm unable to create a typed array of `FooList`.

These typings are not mine, they are from [this library](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c5d04fb2d59f78a403f38ebacff9934def2da5e5/types/marked/index.d.ts#L105).

Does these types mean `FooList` must be an array of `Foo`s and also have an object `bar`? Does each `Foo` object has to contain a property `bar`?

[Here is the link to the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20FooList%20%3D%20Foo%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FooList` is both an array of `Foo` objects, as well as an object that contains a string-valued `bar` property.

If you're willing to use type assertions, it's easy enough to create one since you can just tell the compiler you know what you're doing:

```
var foos: any; // turn off type checking
foos = [{ baz: 'baz1' }, { baz: 'baz2' }];
foos.bar = 'bar';
var fooList: FooList = foos as FooList; // assert type of fooList
```

Creating one of these things *safely*, where the compiler guarantees that you've made something of the right type is a little tricky, but you can do it with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which returns an intersection of its parameter types:

```
const fooList: FooList = Object.assign([{ baz: 'baz' }, { baz: 'baz' }], { bar: 'bar' });
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

---

Please ignore the stuff below; I'm not sure what came over me, but spreading an array into an object is unlikely to work the way anyone wants, since `Array` prototype methods will not be copied.  Just use the above `Object.assign()` solution.

#### Update 1

@CésarAlberca [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717246/typescript-intersection-types-with-array-of-objects-and-an-interface#comment78472184_45717479):

> Thanks! Yours was my preferred solution. What is the equivalent of object assign using the spread operator?

Oh, sure, you could do that:

```
const fooList2: FooList = { ...[{ baz: 'baz' }, { baz: 'baz' }], ...{ bar: 'bar' } };
```

or

```
const fooList3: FooList = { ...[{ baz: 'baz' }, { baz: 'baz' }], bar: 'bar' };
```

Cheers.

Comment: I am not sure how this works, but apparently I am getting TS lint warnings as below: 
`TS2201: The types returned by 'sort(...)' are incompatible between these types.   Type '{ baz: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'FooList'.     Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ baz: string; }[]' but required in type '{ bar: string; }'.`

Comment: Hmm, even without the warnings, spreading an array into an object is a bad idea (since the resulting object will not have any of the expected `Array` prototype methods).  I'm not sure why I suggested that above.  Shame on you, jcalz-from-almost-three-years-ago!  The `Object.assign()` solution is better and should work.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the quick reply. In my case I just provided one more key for the array and made it into a project object inherently, which is also a lot more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`FooList` is an array with items of type `Foo` which also has a string property named `bar`.

Here's how you'd create it:

```
function createFooList(bar: string, ...items: Foo[]): FooList {
    const arr = [] as FooList;
    arr.bar = bar;
    arr.push(...items);
    return arr;
}
```

Or:

```
function createFooList(bar: string, ...items: Foo[]): FooList {
    (items as FooList).bar = bar;
    return items as FooList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/joeyczech/2ftbcfsb/) of usage.

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
    name: string;
}

var people: LinkedList<Person>;
var person: Person = { name: "Joey" };
var childPerson: Person = { name: "James" };
var grandChildPerson: Person = { name: "John" };

people = person;
people.next = childPerson;
people.next.next = grandChildPerson;

alert(JSON.stringify(people));
```

See typescript documentation of [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) and intersection types